# Асинхронность в многопоточном приложении

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Пишу приложение, взаимодействующее с базой данных. Так как запросы к БД относительно тяжелы, то задумался о перемещении кода в отдельные потоки, чтобы не "морозить" интерфейс пользователя.

Помимо запросов к БД этот код осуществляет и запросы к удалённому вебсерверу через сеть. Всё бы ничего, но `QNetworkAccessManager` не предоставляет методов, блокирующих контекст выполнения на время отправки запросов и получения на них ответов. Эта особенность приводит к необходимости организации более сложной модели кода. Придётся совмещать асинхронность (работа с сетью) с многопоточностью (собственно, запросы к БД).

Порядок работы потока:

1. запрос к БД;
2. на основе полученных данных запрос в сеть;
3. на основе полученных данных запрос к БД.

Как реализовать совмещение асинхронности с многопоточностью наиболее простым способом без использования громоздких конструкций, вроде наследования от `QThread` и использования его цикла обработки событий?

Comment: Запрос и получение ответ QNetworkAccessManager можно выполнять в одной функции. У меня код был на примере работы с QWebView. Действия: отправлял запрос, создавал QEventLoop и сигнал finished вешал на loop.quit, после запускал loop. И когда страница прогружалась и ответ приходил, происходил выход из eventLoop. [Пример в функции wait_loading](https://github.com/gil9red/moswar_bot/blob/master/mainwindow.py).

Comment: Спасибо. Оформите как ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример ниже делает асинхронный [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) синхронным, используя [QEventLoop](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qeventloop.html). QNetworkAccessManager подписывает сигнал [finished](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished) на слот [QEventLoop::quit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qeventloop.html#quit), выполняет асинхронный запрос [get](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#get) и запускает `QEventLoop`, который "крутится" пока не придет сигнал `finished`:

```
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkProxyFactory>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QNetworkProxyFactory::setUseSystemConfiguration(true);

    QNetworkAccessManager nam;

    QEventLoop loop;
    QObject::connect(&nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    QNetworkReply *reply = nam.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://google.com")));
    loop.exec();

    qDebug() << reply->url();
    qDebug() << reply->readAll();

    //a.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

Есть теоретическая опасность того, что сигнал `finished` придет раньше запуска `QEventLoop` и код в том месте остановится навсегда, тогда я посоветовал бы на `quit` повесить таймер перед запуском `QEventLoop`, например:

```
// Ждем 10 секунд
QTimer::singleShot(10000, &loop, SLOT(quit()));
```